# Python's timestamp went wrong

Tags: python

I do this:

```
timestamp=long('1455873250789')
print(timestamp)
d=datetime.datetime(timestamp)
```

I get this:

```
1455873250789
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../pycharm-5.0.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File ".../pycharm-5.0.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "....py", line ..., in <module>
d=datetime.datetime(timestamp)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe, that's because your timestamp would be a sometime in the year 48104 and that's not supported? Currently, it is about 1455874000 UNIX time which is 3 orders of magnitude less than your timestamp.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Looks like I just leaked that I have a time machine :) 
Thanks for answer.

Comment: This question probably needs to be removed as resulted from a mistake

Comment: I reckon that rule would half the number of questions on Stack Overflow immediately. ;) We all learn from mistakes - those of others and our own. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000.0)
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 19, 18, 14, 10, 789000)
```

NOTE: `timestamp` should be divided by 1000 before passed to the method, because the given timestamp's unit is millisecond while `fromtimestamp` accepts seconds (which is the official UNIX timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

timestamp = int('1455873250789'[:-3])
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
```

This will strip the last three characters from your timestamp string, essentially converting the timestamp from milliseconds to seconds. With `fromtimestamp()` you can convert a Unix timestamp in seconds to a `datetime` object.